# Are there multiple versions and what are the differences?

Tags: alternate-version, the-chronicles-of-riddick

I just watched a version of The Chronicles of Riddick that contained scenes that were not in the UK cinema release or the original UK DVD release.

The scenes added some extra Furyon mysticism and exposition (Riddick has dreams explaining his origin and the reason the Furyons hate the Necromongers among other differences).

Are there multiple versions? What are the key differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

There is an extended Unrated Director's cut which is 14+ minutes longer

> Director David N. Twohy had to re-cut his stylish science-fiction movie for the theatrical release. The changes are as follows:
>
> Censorship: 23 cuts
>
> Eroticism: 5 cuts
>
> Bigger additional plot scenes: 13, new added visions mostly
>
> Audio censorship: At least 4 times, (slitting sounds, moaning, screaming etc.). The complete fight in the hangar at Crematoria (almost) shown without sound in theatrical version, music dominating there. DC has background music only in these scenes, screaming and special effects are included.

For a full list of the changes see: https://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=1895